# How to get the system active input method editor(IME) with electron api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I am using electron to develop cross platform desktop apps.Now I want to get the **active** input method editor(IME) like sougou ime or microsoft pinyin. I 've read the electron docs but i get nothing about this. Maybe node.js has such api about IME.Please help me.Thanks!

[[ img ] sougou pinyin in tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en4Ij.png)